# Fazer teste sem "sujar" (adicionar dados) o banco de dados

Tags: java, postgresql, testes, jdbc, junit

Estou tendo problema em fazer teste de integração. Testo minhas funções de banco de dados. Minha aplicação web não utiliza nenhum *framework* de conexão de banco de dados e não estou conseguindo fazer testes sem sujar o meu banco de dados.

Queria saber como fazer testes sem que eu insira dados no banco de dados e altere as informações da minha aplicação. Qual funções e classes devo utilizar?

Só estou achando soluções para hibernate.

Comment: o que seria "sujar o bd?

Comment: Sujar seria inserir dados no banco de dados tora hora que eu faço teste

Comment: Por que não usas um banco de teste?

Comment: ou exporta ele para um arquivo de backup, e retorna depois?

Comment: Porque minha aplicação vai crescer muito. O problema não é fazer o teste, que é algo que eu estou conseguindo.

Comment: Você está fazendo testes manuais ou automatizados?

Comment: E se você deletasse os dados inseridos nos testes?

Comment: @helciodasilva é uma boa opção. É a melhor q eu utilizando. Mas de qualquer afeta meu banco, no fato de gerar muitos id's que no futuro serão apagados e também quando minha aplicação começar a rodar, não seri legal eu roda direto o banco. Algo que simula-se ele seria o q mais me atenderia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar um *database* para produção e um outro para os seus testes. Coloque o nome do *database* em questão a ser utilizado em um arquivo de configuração, de forma a ter um arquivo de configuração para a sua base de produção e um para os seus testes. Também é possível colocar no arquivo de configuração, a URL do banco de dados, driver utilizado, nome de usuário, senha, etc.

Feito isso, antes de você iniciar os seus testes, você invoca algum método que seja responsável por criar ou limpar a base de dados (você pode utilizar as anotações `@Before` ou `@BeforeClass` caso esteja usando o JUnit 4 ou `@BeforeEach` ou `@BeforeAll` caso esteja usando o JUnit 5). Para isso, basta rodar algum script contendo todas as instruções `DROP TABLE` necessárias para se destruir qualquer banco de dados anterior existente e em seguida rodar o conjunto de instruções `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, `INSERT` e `UPDATE` necessárias para se recriar e repopular a base de dados. Você também pode optar por usar um banco de dados em memória para os testes, o que melhora o desempenho e simplifica o processo de recriação deles. Entretanto, essas abordagens podem introduzir alguns problemas:

- As diferenças entre o banco de dados em arquivos físicos e em memória podem comprometer os testes.
- Caso utilize um banco de dados físico para os testes, o processo de destruir e recriar o banco de dados pode ser bastante oneroso (pode ser oneroso até mesmo em alguns casos com banco de dados em memória).

Por conta desse problemas, convém que você tente utilizar o banco de dados sujo entre um teste e outro se possível (apenas não use nunca o banco de dados de produção), limpando o banco de dados existente antes do primeiro teste e utilizando-o até o último. Por outro lado, esse procedimento de reutilizar o banco de dados sujo também tem o seu problema:

- A independência e isolamento entre os seus testes pode ficar comprometida, fazendo com que um teste possa interferir no outro.

Essa perda de isolamento é o preço a se pagar para não ter os testes tão onerosos em termos de desempenho. E portanto, se for utilizada, deve ser feita com cuidado e de forma planejada, para não acabar por comprometer a qualidade dos testes.

Assim sendo, para garantir o melhor equilíbrio entre desempenho, independência dos testes e fidelidade com o banco de dados físico, convém você separar os testes em categorias. Aqueles que podem ser rodados em memória e aqueles que precisam do banco de dados em arquivos físicos. Aqueles que podem rodar em bases sujas por testes anteriores e aqueles que precisam da base zerada. Fica mais fácil de se lidar com todos esses diferentes casos ao utilizar-se múltiplas bases de testes distintas.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente o indicado é utilizar um banco em memória para realizar os testes. O banco será criado e carregado apenas para testar, ao final dos testes o banco será destruído.

Você pode utilizar o banco normal também, contanto que seja um banco criado especificamente para teste. Você não deve usar o mesmo banco para testar e para rodar a aplicação.